# Identical Controllers and FXML files but only one works. Why?

Tags: javafx, controller, initialization, scenebuilder

Tab2 and Tab3 are the same in every way except for the numbers 2 and 3, yet only one functions properly. Specifically, when injecting the main controller into each tab

```
    package controller.tab;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import controller.MainController;

public class Tab2Controller {

    private MainController main;

    @FXML public Label lbl2;
    @FXML private TextField txt2;
    @FXML private Button btn2Save;
    @FXML private Button btn2Load;

    @FXML private void btn2SaveClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Btn 2 save clicked");       
        lbl2.setText(txt2.getText());
    }

    @FXML private void btn2LoadClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Btn 2 load clicked");
        lbl2.setText(main.loadLblTextFromTab1());
    }

    public void init(MainController mainController) {
        main = mainController;
        System.out.println("IS 2 ON?");
    }
```

This is the fxml file of Tab2.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="226.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.tab.Tab2Controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lbl2" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="Default Tab3 text" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt2" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn2Save" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="113.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn2SaveClicked" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Save text" />
      <Button fx:id="btn2Load" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="113.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn2LoadClicked" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Load from Tab1" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The print in init only works in one of the tabs. No errors show up on the console. It is not a mixup of fx:ids.

This is the main controller where init is called.

```
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import controller.tab.Tab1Controller;
import controller.tab.Tab3Controller;
import controller.tab.Tab4Controller;
import controller.tab.Tab5Controller;

public class MainController {
    @FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller;
    @FXML Tab3Controller tab3Controller;
    @FXML Tab4Controller tab4Controller;
    @FXML Tab5Controller tab5Controller;

    @FXML public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        tab1Controller.init(this);
        System.out.println("Tab 1 Initialized");
        tab3Controller.init(this);
        System.out.println("Tab 3 Initialized");
        tab4Controller.init(this);
        System.out.println("Tab 4 Initialized");
        tab5Controller.init(this);
        System.out.println("Tab 5 Initialized");
    }

    public String loadLblTextFromTab1() {
        return tab1Controller.lbl1.getText();
    }

    public void setTab3LabelText(String text) {
        tab3Controller.lbl3.setText(text);
    }

    public void updateLogger(String text) {
        tab4Controller.txtArea4.appendText(text + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Where and how are you loading the FXML files? 2. Where are you calling `init()`? Also, if they are identical, what is the point in having two of them?

Comment: Everything it is ok here you made some mistake in another place.

Comment: Identical because I'm trying to figure out what the problem is. One of them works, the other doesn't. I added the main controller where init() is called to the post.